# Unable to upload file on FTp

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, files, upload

My server is **CentOS-6.2-64bit**.

I have made following changes in `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = 7G 
post_max_size = 6G
upload_max_filesize = 5G
```

But unable to upload 5GB file on server.

Guide me to what changes are required to make this happen?

Answer (score -1):

Change `upload_max_filesize` to `6G`.